# Workflow, Create list item to another site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

New to share point, don't have any .asp skills. I have 2 sites (for permission reasons) I need site A to be able to create a workflow to update a list on site B. I am able to use the "Create list item" and update a list on site B with a workflow from site B. But because of permissions, the site A users can not use that workflow. (They do not need to see the list just start the workflow) Is there a way to "create list item" and point it to a list on another site? Thank you for your help and sorry to be a newb.

Note: Both sites are on the same domain. Site A = mainurl, Site B = mainurl/sites/nameofsite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately OOB this is not possible. 
As alternative I would like to offer have a look at [Plumsail's Workflow Actions](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack) which contain "[Create List or Library](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/administration/#CreateList)" and "[Create List Item at Any Site](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/documents-list-items-processing/#CreateListItem)" workflow actions.

P.S.: I'm one of developers of the product and I definitely recommend to use it.

Comment: Does this work with SP2013 Foundation?

Comment: Darrell, Unfortunately not. Foundation version doesn't support 2013 workflows.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2013 workflows there is an option to Call HTTP Web Service.  I am working out the details now.  In theory since a list can be POSTed to via REST one should be able to POST across sites.

Answer (score 0):

I too am still working through this.

As Mario correctly points out, the REST call is 2013 Workflow only.

Here's a similar question: [Workflow copying a list item from one site to another site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150163/workflow-copying-a-list-item-from-one-site-to-another-site)

MSDN Article:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

REST Calls with Fiddler: http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/03/more-on-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-with-fiddler-and-spd/

SharePoint Designer: http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/04/using-the-call-http-web-service-rest-calls-in-sharepoint-online-using-spd/

Big shout out to Fabian Williams for all his good work!