# Workflow copying a list item from one site to another site

Tags: workflow, sub-site, copy-item

I have site A (CRM) that contains a manager name. Depending on the manager's name, I'd like for the list item to be copied to site B. How do I get the copying to move from one subsite to another subsite?

NOTE: Sites A and B are both children of the master site.

Comment: What version/edition of SharePoint are you using?  How much access do you have (i.e., site admin, site collection admin, farm admin, etc.)?  How comfortable are you with coded solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Workflow 2013? You can make a REST call inside the workflow to achieve this goal. You just need grant app permissions to your workflow in both sites.

To create a workflow with elevated permissions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx (do the 5-9 steps in both sites, with the same App ID)

To make a REST call inside the workflow: http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/using-sharepoint-rest-services-from.html