# SharePoint subsite List Item to another subsite List Item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, custom-list, 2016

I have two subsites and want to transfer an item from a list on one site to another when the item created but I can't find any reference.

Example: 
http://cnhkvsp2016:8888/lr  - (A) Leave Request
http://cnhkvsp2016:8888/hr  - (B) HR

First, User created a new record in Custom List on (A), then the (B) Custom List will show this record.

Answer (score 2):

Workflow 2013? You can make a REST call inside the workflow to achieve this goal. You just need grant app permissions to your workflow in both sites.

To create a workflow with elevated permissions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx (do the 5-9 steps in both sites, with the same App ID)

To make a REST call inside the workflow: http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/using-sharepoint-rest-services-from.html

[Ref link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150163/workflow-copying-a-list-item-from-one-site-to-another-site)