# SharePoint Designer create or update item to another list in subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to see if there's another way to display an upcoming event web part to various sub sites based on the event category.

[image]

The source list is located in a site collection. I have several subsites with subsites (i.e. SiteCollection > Committees > Social Committee). Each subsite has a separate list for 'Events'

If the category selected for the event is Social Committee, the workflow should also create a list item in the 'Events' list located in the Social Committee subsite.

I've used Query Web Part but I couldn't figure out a way to display the items similar to what I have above (see image). I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this using REST API? I found this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200251/sharepoint-subsite-list-item-to-another-subsite-list-item) but the link for REST API is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better and easier solution using **Data View** web part from this [page](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/).

1. Open parent site in SPD 2013
2. Go to FILE > ADD ITEM > create a NEW PAGE FROM MASTER > Click YES to open in Advance Mode.
3. Once in edit mode, go to INSERT > DATA VIEW > select the list (i.e. Events)
4. Go to LIST VIEW TOOLS > WEB PART > TO SITE GALLERY > OK
5. Click YES to always show List data from current web site.
6. Save the page.
7. From the subsite page, insert a web part > select MISCELLANEOUS category >  add the web part created in step 1-4.
8. Edit the web part accordingly (i.e. edit to only display events appropriate for the subsite).

Now, i just need to figure out how to insert this custom web part in custom page layout, if at all possible.