# Copy Custom list content from one site to another site in same site collection

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, event-receivers

1. I have two different sites in same site collection but two sites language is different
2. I created two custom lists in both sites with same number of site columns and datatypes but display name of site columns are different according to language.

here i want when i create a new item in site1>customlist1 the same item should create in site2>customlist2

how can i do this either custom code or power shell

http://Web1/site1en/aboutus/Lists/customlist1/AllItems.aspx
http://Web1/site1ar/aboutus/Lists/customlist1/AllItems.aspx

if i use event receiver  is it required to deploy as farm solution? and it will work if two sub sites are in different language level

is there any other way just like one console application i can run one time to avoid any farm solution deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An event receiver would work, that would have to be a farm solution. If you have access to the server you could also do this by creating a scheduled PowerShell script that checks/updates the lists...

I would look into if a simple workflow could do the trick.
As your target list is in another site you would have to update that using the [SharePoint Rest API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

Here is a similar question with some resources you can check out: [Workflow copying a list item from one site to another site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150163/workflow-copying-a-list-item-from-one-site-to-another-site)

Comment: is it work bcz source and destination sites are in two different languages ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the out of the box feature "Variations" to achieve this. This feature makes content available to specific audiences on different sites by syncing content from a source variation site to each target variation site.

You could refer to this article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepoint_quick_reads/sharepoint-2013-variations-creation-and-synchronization-of-content-between-source-and-target-sites

Comment: is it work bcz source and destination sites are in two different languages?

Comment: Yes, it would work.