# Workflows bridging across subsites possible?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-permissions, sharepoint-designer-workflow

SharePoint 2013 - SP Online is firewalled

I have the process to automate with workflows:
Flow process: subsite A fill a form --> Subsite A boss review & sign --> Subsite B admin review form --> Subsite B VP approve form --> subsite A retrieves approved doc for processing

Questions:

- is it possible to have a workflow bridging subsites?
- do all parties need to have permission to the relevant subsites?
- would it be easier if instead of subsites, everything was within a single site, with permissions restricted at the document library level? and categories defined by views using metadata

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CORRECTION: Using SharePoint 2016 on-premises. and Designer 2013

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible to use workflow to do something in another site.
   However it is not Out of Box. According to your description, it may
   be better to create an separate form in Sub site B or at least a
   task. You will need to use Rest API to call HTTP service in the
   workflow.

   Reference may be helpful:
   [Workflow, Create list item to another site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139417/workflow-create-list-item-to-another-site)
2. As I am not sure about your detailed plan about this task, only
   general speaking. If you want the user to view, edit files/items in
   the site, then this user need to have enough permissions.
3. If you can put everything in a site and use unique permissions to
   restrict users from certain behaviors, I assume you will avoid a
   bunch of troubles with your workflow.